# Create multiple folders with files inside

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a simple CLI that will create a folder structure and some files. The structure would look something like this:

```
app-name
├── app.py
├── models.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   └── js
├── templates
└── views.py
```

I have taken a look at the `mkdirp` library, but I realized I would have to chain the `mkdirp()` function for each folder I am trying to make and then use the `fs` module to create the individual files.

What I have tried so far is to chain the `mkdirp()` functions back-to-back for each folder that I am trying to create.

```
const path = require('path');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-promise');

mkdirp(path.join(__dirname, 'app-name', 'static', 'css'))
    .then(mkdirp(path.join(__dirname, 'app-name', 'static', 'js')))
    .then(mkdirp(path.join(__dirname, 'app-name', 'static', 'img')))
    .then(mkdirp(path.join(__dirname, 'app-name', 'templates')))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

This approach doesn't seem to be very efficient, especially with different types of arguments that could be passed to the CLI.

I have thought about creating a folder that has the entire folder structure in it as well as the contents of the Python files, then just copy those files. But I am unsure if this is doable.

What would be a good approach to creating this folder and file hierarchy?

Comment: I can't really tell what problem you're trying to solve.  Your chained mkdirp code is completely wrong (you have to put the mkdirp calls into a function reference that you pass to `.then()` rather than call them immediately like you're doing), but if this has something to do with a CLI, then you need to explain that part of the question because this just looks like some hard-coded directory creation, nothing to do with a CLI at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 the CLI doesn't really matter in this case right now. I am looking to see how to create that folder structure with cleaner code is basically what I am asking.

Comment: Show us your input. What input would determine the directory structure your code will try to create?

Comment: @RamtinSoltani for right now the user will just be able to name the main folder (`app-name`)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow exactly what you're looking for.  If you just want to reliably create several directories, then I'd say just create a function that takes an array of paths and you can iterate serially through the array using `.reduce()`:

```
const path = require('path');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp-promise');

function makeAllDirs(root, list) {
    return list.reduce((p, item) => {
        return p.then(() => {
            return mkdirp(path.join(root, item));
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

// usage

let dirs = [
    "app-name/static/css",
    "app-name/static/img",
    "app-name/static/js",
    "app-name/templates"
];

makeAllDirs(__dirname, dirs).then(() => {
   // all done here
}).catch(err => {
   // error here
});
```

Comment: is there a specific reason you chose to use `mkdirp` over `fs`?

Comment: @BugWhisperer - Because it creates parent directories too if needed and it's what the OP used.

Comment: what do you mean it creates parent directories? where does your script create a parent directory or do anything that `fs` cannot do?

Comment: @BugWhisperer - Try passing `app-name/static/css` to the fs module when none of those directories exist yet.  It will fail.  mkdirp will create all in the path that don't exist yet.

Comment: but it will work if you set the `recursive` option to `true`?

Comment: @BugWhisperer - it appears so.  I don't think that used to be there.

Comment: im new to all of this so maybe it is new?? `mkdir` is also asynchronous so no need for promises?? i just figured youre prolly gonna be using `fs` quite a bit if youre creating directories, so why require yet another module that is basically redundant.

Comment: @BugWhisperer - yes that seems to be the case.  You could use the `fs.promises` interface for mkdir with recent versions of nodejs.  Note the original date of this question.

Comment: i guess if you really need to know exactly when the directories have been created. im talking about this right now over [here](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2093) too

Comment: @BugWhisperer - Why is it an issue to know when they've been created with `fs.promises.mkdir()` with `recursive` set to `true`?  Doesn't the returned promise tell you that?

Comment: It's not an issue to know when they've been created, but rather it might be useless or unnecessary to know.

Comment: @BugWhisperer - If you don't want to know when it completed, you can just ignore the returned promise.  Personally, I can't imagine such a scenario because you can't have any code that plans to use it if you don't want to know when it completed or had an error.

Comment: thats my point. if you dont have code that uses it, theres no need to use promises ;)

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what you want based on your input (this might not be the best approach if the structure is provided by the user):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { promisify } = require('util');

function createDirectory(dirPath) {

  return promisify(fs.mkdir)(dirPath);

}

function createFile(filePath, content) {

  return promisify(fs.writeFile)(filePath, content, 'utf-8');

}

function scaffoldProject(projectName) {

  createDirectory(path.join(__dirname, projectName))
  .then(() => {

    return createDirectory(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'static'));

  })
  .then(() => {

    return createDirectory(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'templates'));

  })
  .then(() => {

    return createDirectory(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'static', 'css'));

  })
  .then(() => {

    return createDirectory(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'static', 'img'));

  })
  .then(() => {

    return createDirectory(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'static', 'js'));

  })
  .then(() => {

    // Last argument is the app.py's content
    return createFile(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'app.py'), '');

  })
  .then(() => {

    // Last argument is the models.py's content
    return createFile(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'models.py'), '');

  })
  .then(() => {

    // Last argument is the views.py's content
    return createFile(path.join(__dirname, projectName, 'views.py'), '');

  })
  .then(() => {

    console.log(`Project ${projectName} was successfully scaffolded at ${path.join(__dirname, projectName)}`);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error);

  });

}

// Replace 'test-project' with user input
scaffoldProject('test-project');
```

This uses the `fs` module and turns it's callback API into a Promise API (promisifies). You call `createDirectory` or `createFile` and chain then using `.then()` to control the flow. The `.catch()` catches any errors thrown in the chain.